# Will this work to repair my system after a bad update?

Tags: grub2, updates, uefi, dpkg

A few weeks back, I did an update to my 16.04 install on my laptop. Unfortunately, I had a power loss, and now instead of giving my GRUB menu (it's a Win10 dual-boot setup), it boots directly to a grub> prompt. I ended up switching it over to Win10, but I would like to get 16.04 back so that I can upgrade it to 18.04.

My question is this: Can I use a USB stick of 16.04 to boot into the live version, mount the necessary directories and do "dpkg -a --reconfigure" to complete the update? And if so, will this restore my GRUB menu so that I have dual-boot again?

I really do not want to have to reinstall anything because of the amount of problems getting it onto the laptop in the first place (Acer is not particularly Linux-friendly with their BIOS).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can chroot from the live usb but 18.04 is pre release. With all the changes I would fresh install

Comment: Thanks. 

Unfortunately I wasn't able to boot from the USB stick. For some reason my laptop didn't like either one of the two 16.04 ones I tried, so I found the grub commands I needed elsewhere, and it booted me into Ubuntu. Once I was there, I fixed the bad update, then did another one to make sure everything was current, and that repaired GRUB. My dual-boot is back again!

Now if only I could revive the data hard drive another distro made an LVM...The old NTFS filesystem is there, but I don't know how to bring it back.